# Review apps in Bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I am researching into a DevOps workflow that we can use to replace our current DevOps implementation. We are using Bitbucket cloud to host our repositories.

While researching I stumbled upon "Review Apps" feature of GitLab CI/CD.

Is it possible to achieve something similar using Bitbucket pipelines?

Comment: You can use GITLAB CI/CD but it needs lot of memory server.
Personnally i am using GOGS build with GO combine with DRONE CI.
You can achieve similar to bitbucket pipeline and gitlab ci