# Create environment every Pull Request

Tags: docker, kubernetes, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I am asking a question for some knowledge and knowhow.

I am running a React App where the build is hosted on AWS. I then have an EC2 instance of my backend that using Django REST framework.

I also have some E2E tests, in a different repo, so I have 3 in total, FE, BE and E2E.

However, every time I push a Pull Request, on my bitbucket pipeline, I would like to somehow, have an environment where this specific PR can run and is built. So, it's something like: `pr-125.mydomain.com/app`

I then, want to run my E2E on this specific location and NOT on staging.

I am using docker for my production and staging build deployment.

Is there something like this available and any documentation anywhere?

Regards

Comment: Honestly hard to find if one is not familiar with GitLab, but this question is a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56785248/review-apps-in-bitbucket-pipelines